# NSArray sortedArrayUsingSelector keeps erroring with SIGBART

Tags: iphone, sorting, nsarray

EDIT: Are you even able to use a custom selector with "sortedArrayUsingSelector"? I got this to work using [[ComicArray valueForKey:@"Name"] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

The Exception "Does not recognize selector" is thrown. Anyone know how to sort this?
The ComicArray is filled with ComicDB which is a custom class that contains .Name. I am trying to sort based on ComicDB.Name.

```
//atempt1
NSArray * comicArray2 = [[ComicArray valueForKeyPath:@"ComicDB.Name"] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compareByName:)];

//atempt2       
NSArray * compicArray2 = [ComicArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compareByName:)];

- (NSComparisonResult)compareByName:(id)other
{
    return [[self valueForKeyPath: @"ComicDB.Name"] caseInsensitiveCompare:[other valueForKeyPath: @"ComicDB.Name"]];
}
```

Thanks,
-Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jan 23 2011
I could not get this to work. Instead i used the iOS 4.0 sort method:

```
NSArray * myArraySorted = [ComicArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2)
                          {
                              return [[obj1 valueForKey:@"Name"] caseInsensitiveCompare: [obj2 valueForKey: @"Name"]]; 
                              // return [[obj1 Name] caseInsensitiveCompare: [obj2 Name]];
                          }];
```

Answer (score 3):

sortedArrayUsingSelector: performs the selector on the objects in the array to determine their order. The compareByName: method should be in the ComicDB class. The following implementation will work if you have accessors defined. If you don't, change `Name` to `valueForKey:@"Name"`.

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compareByName:(ComicDB *)other {
    return [[self name] caseInsensitiveCompare:[other name]];
}
```

Comment: Hey, sorry for taking so long to respond. I have been out of town. I am still getting SIGBART -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] . When debugging, i am not even getting into "compareByName".

Comment: Are you sure the objects in the array are ComicDB objects? The console should have the class name of the object throwing the error. This is what is having compareByName: called on it.

Comment: The objects in ComicArray are ComicDB* and the ComicDB* say they are NSManagedObjects